# Найти файлы, созданные пользователем, и подсчитать их размер

Tags: файлы, linux

Файлы пользователя нашел:

```
find . -user username
```

Теперь как подсчитать размер найденных данных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Где-то так:

```
find . -user username  | du -sh
```

s - сумарный размер файлов, h - "в человеческом формате".

Comment: Нет, боюсь, что так он поиск-то выполняет, но вот подсчитывает размер всех файлов в каталоге, а не найденных...  

Сделал такой вывод, просто выполнив 

    du -sh

и в связке с find.

Comment: Тогда, видимо, так:

    find ~/ -user vadim  -ls | awk '{z += $7;} END {print z;}'

`z += $7;` - суммируем 7 столбец, где указан размер, и в самом конце выводим накопленную сумму.